# PHP Dompdf-No block-level parent found. Not good. (Line 66)

Tags: javascript, php, dompdf

So,I have dompdf installed for a project of mine,however when I try converting into PDF I get the following error:

An uncaught Exception was encountered

```
Type: DOMPDF_Exception
Message: No block-level parent found. Not good.
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\libraries\dompdf\include\inline_positioner.cls.php

Line Number: 66

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\libraries\dompdf\include\frame_decorator.cls.php
Line: 471
Function: position

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\libraries\dompdf\include\text_frame_reflower.cls.php
Line: 340
Function: position

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\libraries\dompdf\include\frame_decorator.cls.php
Line: 477
Function: reflow

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\libraries\dompdf\include\page_frame_reflower.cls.php
Line: 169
Function: reflow

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\libraries\dompdf\include\frame_decorator.cls.php
Line: 477
Function: reflow

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\libraries\dompdf\include\dompdf.cls.php
Line: 680
Function: reflow

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\application\controllers\bo_engine\Commande_engine.php
Line: 611
Function: render

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once))
```

Not sure why is this happening,I looked around on google and there's little to no matches on my problem,on my code,at least....I tried all solutions concerning this problem,from changing CSS,to reinstalling dompdf,to trying older versions to changing:

```
< html>

...

<\html>
```

to :

```
< html><\html>
```

yet the problem persists, I don't understand if the problem with me or my Project.

Apologies in advance if the error was my fault in any way; I'm still new to this and I'm still learning.

Comment: Your question has a much better chance of getting an answer if you read, and act, on the following: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: My **best guess** at the moment is malformed HTML/CSS. See: [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/) and [CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). It's a good start, but may not solve the problem.

Comment: @AxelX: can you refer to following post at their GIT repository. Can you try with a different version of dompdf ?
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1494

Comment: I already tried the different versions,nothing useful,I also made a post there 2 days ago,there was no reply,I'm still waiting tho for one